# Poisson distribution - Insurance claims

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $N(t)$ denote the number of claims received by an insurance company from time $0$ to time $t$. Assume that $N(t)$ is a Poisson process, and the continuous time index $t \ge 0$ denotes days from January 1st, 0:00.00. Set the intensity $\lambda(t) = 3$.

What is the probability that there are more than 175 claims before March 1st (59 days)?

So, the task is to calculate the following probability: $$P[N(59) \gt 175] = 1 - exp(-\lambda t)\sum_{k=0}^{175} \frac{(\lambda t)^k}{k!} $$

with the intensity (average number of insurance claims), $\lambda$, equal to $3 \frac{claims}{day}$. With the increasing $k$, the term $ \frac{(\lambda t)^k}{k!}$ gives med a "math error" when I try to calculate it. I don't understand what I'm missing here. Is the average, $\lambda = 3 \frac{claims}{day}$, wrong? If I get this right the average number of claims during the 59 days is $3\times59=177$, which is accounted for in the Poisson formula.

Comment: If the problem is just computing the probability you can use some special software. For example in R all you need to do is write **ppois(175, 177, lower.tail= FALSE)**

Comment: Computing things like (177^175)/(175)! is likely to give you some numerical error. Since $\lambda t$ is fairly large in your case you could try to use a normal approximation of the poisson distribution instead. Computation in R shows that such approximation gives you an error of $2\%$ on the original value of the cumulative distribution function I.e. the value you are looking for is $53,9..\%$ whereas the normal approximation gives the value $55,9..\%$.